# will mysql_fetch_array fail if connection lost during the fetch?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to loop multiple times through my query results, and I have 2 ways in mind:

```
1-        
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res ,  MYSQL_ASSOC)
{
array_push($new_arr , $data);
}
foreach($sites as $s){
  foreach($new_arr as $d)
  {
  //some code
  }
}

2-
foreach($sites as $s){
  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res ,  MYSQL_ASSOC)
  {
  //some code
  }
mysql_data_seek($res,0);//set the pointer 
}
```

My question: I think option 2 is more efficient but what if I lose connection to db during the mysql_fetch_array(option 2)? I get allot of results; this will take around 10-20 minutes.  Will that affect the query results($res) or are they safe?

Comment: If the connection fails during the fetch, you won't have anything in `mysql_fetch_array`. Further, you need to stop using `mysql_` functions as they are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). You should use `mysql_error` to try to catch errors.

Comment: its gonna take 10-20 minutes? regardless of the method chosen, you better think long and hard about detecting failure, and how to recover. forget a silly mysql connection, the entire server can can down.

Comment: njk: I run the query and get the data from the DB, once I have it in $res I run the fetch_array, You are saying that if - while I am in the mysql_fetch_array loop- the connection to the server i got the data from is lost, then $res will be empty?

Comment: rambo - it took almost 2 hours, I needed to update servers which are very far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is mapped into a buffer assigned by the mysql client when you execute mysql_query() therefore losing the connection is irrelevant. The first method you cite will create a further copy of the data as a PHP array - which is not very efficient.

Also, WTF is the nested loop ($sites) doing? It looks like either your data is not mormalized or you've got a very bad algorithm.

Comment: Tnx for the answer, I also prefer option 2, as mentioned in question.                                                                        I need to manipulate data from one main server (the results of the query) and insert it into a number of different servers ($sites - are the servers i need to insert the data into), an alghorithem upgrade is welcome

Comment: I also checked it and symcbean is correct, I closed the connection after selecting the data and before the fetch_array, $res still had the data. tnx.

Comment: If you're copying the data to other DBs then you might consider using the federated engine such that the data is sent directly under the control of PHP rather than via PHP

Comment: I looked up the federated engine, it wont help in my case since I only need to insert rows to an existing table in a remote DB, and not create a new table. Or do I need to read some more about it (any refrences?)

Comment: Using the federated engine you can simply INSERT INTO localtable (...) SELECT ... FROM federatedtable WHERE....